# how to solve the algebra equation using algebra.js

Tags: javascript, html, algebra

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/algebra.css">

<script src="js/algebra-0.2.5.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.6.0/katex.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.6.0/katex.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="myEquation"></div>
<div id="mySolution"></div>

<script>
window.onload=function(){



var expr1 = new Expression("x");
expr1 = expr1.add(2);
expr1 = expr1.multiply(4);

var expr2 = new Expression("x");
expr2 = expr2.multiply("y");
expr2 = expr2.multiply(new Fraction(1, 3));
expr2 = expr2.add(4);

var expr3 = expr1.multiply(expr2);

console.log("(" + expr1.toString() + ")(" + expr2.toString() + ") = " + expr3.toString());

}
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

I have some code not get any data what is error my code please correct it.and how to solve the algebra equation for example 10x2+10y-90=100 please help me. in that code how to use algebra.js.

Comment: You'll have to provide more context. Why did you write this code in the first place? What output do you want to get and what output do you get instead?

Comment: copy and paste from algebra.js but not showing a result.

Answer (score 0):

You miss variable definition, change your script to

```
var Fraction = algebra.Fraction;
var Expression = algebra.Expression;
var Equation = algebra.Equation;

var expr1 = new Expression("x");
expr1 = expr1.add(2);
expr1 = expr1.multiply(4);

var expr2 = new Expression("x");
expr2 = expr2.multiply("y");
expr2 = expr2.multiply(new Fraction(1, 3));
expr2 = expr2.add(4);

var expr3 = expr1.multiply(expr2);

console.log("(" + expr1.toString() + ")(" + expr2.toString() + ") = " + expr3.toString());
```

These are missed statements

```
var Fraction = algebra.Fraction;
var Expression = algebra.Expression;
var Equation = algebra.Equation;
```

[Here a working pen](http://codepen.io/berets76/pen/LkJxRX)